# Gradleの-Dオプションの値がJavaプログラムで取得できない

Tags: java, gradle

System.getPropertyで値を取得できないです

### 環境

Java   1.8
Gradle 2.14

### コマンド

```
gradle test -Denv=test
```

### ソース

Sample.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;


public class Sample {

    @Test
    public void testHoge() {
        String hoge = System.getProperty("env");
        assertEquals("test", hoge);
    }

}
```

builde.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

### 結果

```
Sample > testHoge FAILED
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<test> but was:<null>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at Sample.testHoge(Sample.java:13)
```

1 test completed, 1 failed

Answer (score 2):

`gradle test -Denv=test` とした場合、gradleコマンドによるGradleプロセスに対してシステムプロパティ `env=test` を指定したことになります。Gradleプロセスから起動されるテスト用のJavaプロセスには届きません。

Gradleプロセスから起動されるテスト用のJavaプロセスに、Gradleプロセスと同じシステムプロパティを渡すためには以下のように設定します。これはJavaプラグインの `Test` 型のタスクに対してGradleプロセス自体のシステムプロパティ(`System.properties`)をすべて、起動するJavaプロセスのシステムプロパティ(`systemProperties`)に設定しています。

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

ちなみに、テストではなくアプリケーション用のJavaプロセスにシステムプロパティを引き継ぐには以下のようにします。

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```